# Chrome default scrollbars

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane, scrollbars

I've set up a Wordpress site and I want to use custom scroll bars in certain divs. I'm using the WP jScrollPane plugin. And it works fine except for in Chrome on a Windows machine.

The Chrome default scroll bars show up over the top of WP jScrollPane's. Any idea on how to hide those? It looks fine in Chrome on a Mac, but not on a PC.

Thank you in advance for any help. I'm kind of new to using/setting up plugins so pardon my ignorance.

You can see the problem here, only if you use a PC though,
http://mbigelowphotographer.com/weddings/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set the CSS property overflow: hidden; on the div holding the content (ngg-galleryoverview jspScrollable), this should fix the issue in Chrome.

Comment: Yup that worked. I can't believe I totally overlooked that. Thank you Cassie. Take care.